# Is there a no format option in ApexSQL Refactor

Tags: ssms

I use ApexSQL Refactor and love it for the SQL formatting option.  There are times though that I don't want certain blocks of code to be formatted.  SQL Pretty Printer had an option to block certain sections of code off from the formatter. You just added...

```
--begin_no_format
--end_no_format
```

Just not having any luck finding it in the options or documentation.

Thanks

Comment: Would be awesome :)